# Laravel 5.3 NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to setup a Laravel 5.3 project. I have create the project and starting the 'localhost//public' shows the welcome screen just fine.

When adding a test entry in the web.php file like

```
Route::get('about', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

An then trying to access this as 'localhost//public/about' I get this NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: error. I'm really puzzled as to whats wrong.

In the 5.2 version, with the routes.php, it worked perfectly fine.

Regs.,

Erik

Comment: why this ?localhost//public/about why not just localhost/public/about

Comment: Too late but for anyone else that sees this, it was most likely something in the `RouteServiceProvider` that was not changed in line with Laravel 5.3 changes. Compare that file to the one in the laravel/laravel repo.

Answer (score 0):

**NotFoundHttpException** means Laravel can't found the requested route. Hence, you are trying to access something which doesn't exist that's why it is throwing **NotFoundHttpException**.

Try to access your route like

```
localhost/public/about
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its a strange story when using artisan route:list the about neatly pops up. However when accessing through Chrome i wasn't able to load it. I have dropped the whole www directory and started afresh. Now it works. Must have been something lingering around.

Thx.,

Erik

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a 'public' prefix for the web routes in app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php like so:

```
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => 'public',
        ], function ($router) {
             require base_path('routes/web.php');
        });
    }
```